# Enlarge Linux Kernel Log Buffer more that 2M

Tags: logging, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, printk

I am in the process of collecting some sort of Linux Kernel activities. I have placed multiple `printk` statements with in the kernel source code and would like to monitor those during regular kernel activities. Unfortunately, I have realized that the Kernel Log Buffer size (`CONFIG_LOG_BUF_SHIFT`) cannot be more that 2^21 which is essentially equal to 2M entries.

Is there any other way to record more than 2M Kernel messages ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can set the kernel log buffer to `log_buf_len=4M` in your `/boot/grub/grub.conf`. This should increase the log buffer size to 4 MiB. Note you can also edit the `grub` during boot, and append the `log_buf_len=4M` at the end of the line starting with the `kernel ...`.

`CONFIG_LOG_BUF_SHIFT` shows the default size of the kernel log buffer not the maximum size, you can set this to larger value but would require to recompile the kernel.

```
ex:
2 ^ 19 = 512 KiB
2 ^ 20 = 1 MiB
2 ^ 21 = 2 MiB
2 ^ 22 = 4 MiB
```

Which flavor or kernel version of Linux are you on, this works well on SuSE and RHEL.

Comment: `log_buf_len` doesn't seems to exist anymore in `grub.cfg`. What's the alternative?